# Why do the isotherms bulge north of the Bering Strait in winter, and bulge south of the Bering Strait in summer?

Tags: climate, temperature, ocean-currents

My grade-7 geography textbook contains these world average temperatures for January and July.

> [image]
> Average air temperatures in January (winter in the northern hemisphere)

> [image]
> Average air temperatures in July (summer in the northern hemisphere)

In these images, we can see differing behavior in the [Bering Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Strait) (between Russia and Alaska): in winter (top), the [isotherm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isotherm) bulges north of the Bering Strait, while towards the south we see fairly straight isotherms.  However, in summer, the isotherm bulges south of Bering Strait.  I'm guessing this is related to the [Global Conveyor Belt](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/education/tutorial_currents/05conveyor2.html), but I'm not sure.

**Question**: Why do the isotherms bulge north of the Bering Strait in winter, and bulge south of the Bering Strait in summer?